# Inform when folder is empty in Python?

Tags: python, exception

I am searching for files in a path but some subfolders are empty. Therefore an exception should be used.

If an encounter with an empty folder takes place this error occurs.

> FionaValueError: No dataset found at path
>   '/Users\user\Desktop\testn\43003\CBOUND' using drivers: *

So I made an exception for this error:

```
folder = Path(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\testn")
shapefiles =glob('/*/*/Desktop/testn/*/*')
#shapefiles =glob('/*/*/Desktop/testm/*/*,recursive = True')

shapefiles
try:
    gdf = pandas.concat([
    geopandas.read_file(shp)
    for shp in shapefiles
    ],sort=True).pipe(geopandas.GeoDataFrame)
    gdf.to_file(folder / 'compiled.shp')
except FionaValueError as ex:
    if shp==[]: #if subfolder is empty print name of folder and subfolder is empty
        print(shp + 'is empty')
```

and gives

```
NameError: name 'FionaValueError' is not defined
```

So what I need is:

1.Print the name of the folder and subfolder that is empty

2.Fix the error that is not recognized in the exception.

Comment: You need to import FionaValueError from wherever it is defined.

Comment: You could also check if the folder is empty before working on it. This can be done with os.listdir (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import this error - also see the [docs](http://toblerity.org/fiona/fiona.html):

```
from fiona.errors import FionaValueError
```

To check if a folder is empty you can use a pattern as:

```
if not os.listdir(path):
    print(f'{path} is empty')
```

To print the actual empty paths you can rewrite the list comprehension to a standard loop:

```
from fiona.errors import FionaValueError
import os
import glob
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd 
import path

folder = path.Path(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\testn")
shapefiles = []
for shpfile in glob.iglob('/*/*/Desktop/testn/*/*'):
    try:
        shapefiles.append(geopandas.read_file(shpfile))
    except FionaValueError as ex:
        if not os.listdir(shpfile):
            print(f'{shpfile} is empty')

gdf = pd.concat(shapefiles, sort=True).pipe(gpd.GeoDataFrame)
gdf.to_file(folder / 'compiled.shp')
```

Comment: can you also help with the first subquestion? `1.Print the name of the folder and subfolder that is empty. and check if it is empty

`

Comment: Yes but what about using it in the loop I have and through the glob process? Check the code I have posted to see the specific case.

Comment: says: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Path'

Comment: Do you know why this isn't working? `for shpfile in glob.glob('/*/*/Desktop/testm/** ,recursive = True'):`

Comment: There is an apostrophe in the wrong place, think it should be: `for shpfile in glob.iglob('/*/*/Desktop/testm/**', recursive=True)`. I also thought the pattern was `**/*` (so double and then single star). And it could help to remove the first stars + add an extension in your glob :)

Comment: Great, why put iglob instead of the glob function. in this case it doesn't make a difference I think.

Comment: It won't make much of a difference, but I would say that in general `generators` are preferred over `lists`. Just to get used to them for when it does matter :)